# TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function (Vue/Electron)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, electron-builder

Trying to access electron from within vue and it throws a TypeError.

```
TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
  at getElectronPath (index.js?bdb9:7)
  at Object.eval (index.js?bdb9:18)
  at eval (index.js:20)
```

Searching the google wasn't much help. I found one post suggesting that adding the following to vue.config.js would do the trick. That did not work for me.

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using the following

- macOS Catalina 10.15.3
- Vue 3.0
- vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder
- node v13.3.0

package.json:

```
   {
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.5",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.2.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.2.3",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.2.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "electron": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.25.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "^1.4.6",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ],
  "main": "background.js"
}
```

test.vue:

```
<script>

  import { remote } from 'electron'

  export default {
   created() {
      // ERROR THROWN HERE!!
      console.log('APP VERSION', ipcRenderer.app.getVersion())
    }
  }
</script>
```

background.js

```
'use strict'
import { app, protocol, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'

import {
  createProtocol,
  /* installVueDevtools */
} from 'vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib'
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win

// Scheme must be registered before the app is ready
protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([{scheme: 'app', privileges: { secure: true, standard: true } }])

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, 
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
  } })

  if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
    win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
    if (!process.env.IS_TEST) win.webContents.openDevTools()
  } else {
    createProtocol('app')
    // Load the index.html when not in development
    win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
  }

  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
  })
}

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', async () => {
  if (isDevelopment && !process.env.IS_TEST) {
    // Install Vue Devtools
    // Devtools extensions are broken in Electron 6.0.0 and greater
    // See https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/issues/378 for more info
    // Electron will not launch with Devtools extensions installed on Windows 10 with dark mode
    // If you are not using Windows 10 dark mode, you may uncomment these lines
    // In addition, if the linked issue is closed, you can upgrade electron and uncomment these lines
    // try {
    //   await installVueDevtools()
    // } catch (e) {
    //   console.error('Vue Devtools failed to install:', e.toString())
    // }

  }
  createWindow()
})


// Exit cleanly on request from parent process in development mode.
if (isDevelopment) {
  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    process.on('message', data => {
      if (data === 'graceful-exit') {
        app.quit()
      }
    })
  } else {
    process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
      app.quit()
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: which Node.js version?

Comment: Could you show that which function call throws the exception?

Comment: _what_ throws a type error? The browser, or the server? Because `fs` does not exist in the browser, there is no filesystem access, only URL access. If you have a bundler (it looks like you do?) bundle in those resources by using the appropriate loader, pointing to the appropriate path glob.

Comment: @GuerricP edited the question to include those requests